# Labels keep having black background in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I have an app that uses a form which has a white background.The issue is that the labels on the form all have a black background which is not what i want at all.
The code is:

```
     Welcome.getUnselectedStyle().setFgColor(0x0000ff);
     Welcome.getUnselectedStyle().setBgColor(0xffffff);
     Welcome.getUnselectedStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
     Welcome.getSelectedStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
     Welcome.getSelectedStyle().setFgColor(0x0000ff);
     form.setLayout(layout);
     form.getStyle().setBgColor(0xffffff);
     hi.addComponent(Welcome);
```

The "Welcome" label shows a black background...how can i prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
 Welcome.getUnselectedStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
 Welcome.getSelectedStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
```

Made the background transparent. I guess you meant 255 for the rest of the code to make sense.